# Mediawiki AuthManager and SessionManager SSO

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am currently using 1.24.x and using LoginForm class and FauxRequest to login the remote (and create it locally if it doesn't exist) but this feature is being removed in 1.27.x so I am forced to write with a new standard using AuthManager and SessionMamager. I also will be upgrading to 1.31 as soon as LTS version of it comes out.
While reading, AuthManager and SessionManager, I just can't understand how can I authenticate external users. I also looked at the extension pluggableSSO which uses PluggableAuth but can't understand it as well. 
Can someone please point me to a straightforward example of how can I authenticate a user if I have a user id and user name? and if that user doesn't exist, how can I create one and authenticate them locally?

Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing at least the vague details of how the SSO system works.

Answer (score 0):

If someone like me who is very new to MediaWiki, there is a solution for SSO called PluggableAuth and Auth_Remoteuser.
I picked PluggableAuth which is implemented based on AuthManager and it is very easy to integrate. 
All we need is to define a global variable $PluggableAuth_Class and implement the following methods in it:

```
public function authenticate( &$id, &$username, &$realname, &$email, &$errorMessage )
public function saveExtraAttributes( $id )
public function deauthenticate( User &$user )
```

More information can be found on:
[PluggableAuth](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PluggableAuth)